# C# SEO URL generated from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, friendly-url

I'm currently working on a CMS.
It allows users to create pages/subpages++++

The pages have an ID + FrienldyName to be found.
My question is:

How and where do I generate the routing based on all pages found in the database.
So it won't be like

"www.page.com/goto?pageId=1&productId=1"

But

"www.page.com/products/1"

P.s. I am not using asp.mvc.

Comment: What makes you think `products/1` is better than `products?productId=1`?

Comment: That is mosley for the looks. The main focus is on replaceing ?pageid=... by the pageName

ps CMS checks for double names so that is not an issue

Comment: You mentioned SEO though, an example of a better URL would be `products/chair`.

Comment: That might be a problem since product names are allowd to have duplicates

Comment: Then look at how this website does it, note that the question title is actually irrelevant (you can type anything you like as long as you keep the number the same)

Comment: www.page.com/products/1/chair is possible. But the main question is how and where to handle this. I find a lot about ASP.MVC and automatic routing generation from .aspx files. but the CMS creates the pages

Comment: You are developing the CMS though, or not?

Comment: Stil in development, 60/70% done, had kept designing for friendly urls in mind. Only starting on it now. Main focus was on backend

Comment: One way to do this is to create a routing engine. I'd imagine that as your CMS becomes more complicated, you'd benefit from one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480999/url-routing-asp-net-webpages-cshtml-without-mvc

Comment: @ara06 That is for asp-webpages specific. I am not using any extentions, just the .net framework (in the backend) Frontend has Jquery and then some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for URL routing or rewriting.

Here's an example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series